# KendoUI TreeList Change Expand/Collapse Icon

Tags: css, kendo-ui, treelist

Im trying to change the default expand/collapse icons to bigger icons. I've set the following css change which doesnt seem to be taking any effect:

```
.k-treelist .k-minus {        
     background: url('../img/Misc/customCollapsedIcon.png') center center;
}

.k-treelist .k-plus {
    background: url('../img/Misc/customExpandedIcon.png') center center;
 }
```

Can anyone give me some advice on what I need to change for this to take affect on  the TreeList?

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the exact height and width for each new icon, in these CSS rules.

If that doesn't work, make sure that other CSS rules aren't overriding these rules.

Answer (score 0):

with the 2016 Q1 version you need to use

```
.k-treelist .k-i-expand{
background: url("/Content/...") center center no-repeat // i'm on an asp.net web app
}
.k-treelist .k-i-collapse{
background: url("/Content/...") center center no-repeat
}
```

i was using font awesome icons so i had to go to http://fa2png.io/ and convert chevron-right to a png and save it 16x16